# DropDownList - First Item in the List is not posting back properly but all the others work

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have this DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlSort" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ApplyFilters" AutoPostBack="True">
   <asp:ListItem Value="0">Sort By Relevancy</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="1">Sort By Product Code</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Sort By Product Description</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3">Sort By Price - Lowest</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="4">Sort By Price - Highest</asp:listitem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

I am setting the option to be initially selected in the Page_Load in `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` which defaults to "0". If I select `Sort By Product Code` (or any other option) it will call `ApplyFilters` without a problem. If I then change the Drop Down to the first option, the AutoPostBack is fired but it doesn't go into the `ApplyFilters` code.

If I change the markup to this:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlSort" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ApplyFilters" AutoPostBack="True">
   <asp:ListItem Value="-1">First Option</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="0">Sort By Relevancy</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="1">Sort By Product Code</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Sort By Product Description</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3">Sort By Price - Lowest</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="4">Sort By Price - Highest</asp:listitem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

then selecting Sort By Relevancy will work properly after selecting any other option BUT selecting First Option won't (as in the first example).

I am using ASP.NET 2.0.

1. I have checked the control hierarchy and the view state is enabled for all the controls.
2. I have tried explicitly setting EnableViewState="true" without any success.

Does anyone have any ideas as all the information I have seen on this points to the view state being false and in an update panel - Neither of which are true in my case.

EDIT: I have put a dummy entry in for now as the first entry but this is not ideal.

Comment: ViewStateMode=Enabled on drop downlist or turn on ViewStateMode in web.config

Comment: I'm afraid that your code as you describe it is totally standard. Have you debugged to see if you detect something wrong?

Comment: @MMK - Did you read the last 2 points of my post?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi - I am not really sure what to debug. The page posts back but doesn't call ApplyFilters. It's that part in the middle that seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.

Your event is `OnSelectedIndexChanged`, if open the dropdown and select the already selected option, asp.net will not detect that as a change.

Only when you select a different value, will the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` be fired.

I suggest having a default value in place, like in your second example, just more readable:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlSort" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ApplyFilters" AutoPostBack="True">
   <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Sort order</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="0">Sort By Relevancy</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="1">Sort By Product Code</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="2">Sort By Product Description</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="3">Sort By Price - Lowest</asp:listitem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="4">Sort By Price - Highest</asp:listitem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

If you have a default sort order, you can set it on page load

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   ddlSort.Text = 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you read my post properly. I said - I select something else THEN select option 1 again and it doesn't call ApplyFilters. I shouldn't have to have a bogus entry as the first entry to fix this. The value is selected based on a value in the Url which "should" be set in ApplyFilters.

Comment: Are you saying, on your first selection it calls `ApplyFilters` and then when you select the first option, it doesn't? That seems very unlikely.

Comment: That is what I am saying. If you select any of the other options it works, then after selecting that other option and re-selecting the first one, it doesn't call ApplyFilters (it does postback though).